# Use a USB device on QNX Neutrino

Tags: dll, usb, shared-libraries, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am trying to use a USB device (mass storage at first and then an OTG device such as a keyboard) on an AX12260 card. QNX Neutrino is the RTOS on which the card is running. I tried to follow [this guide](https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.6.0.update/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide/topic/hardware_USB.html) to be able to read/write on a USB storage but I didn't succeed.
First, the `usb -vvv` output is null, so I figured I had to start the USB stack. The `pci -vvv` command tells me that there are two controlers: ohci and ehci. So I proceed to start the stack with `io-usb -d ehci` (I also tried with ohci option) but it fails: the dll cannot be loaded. The exact output is:

```
DLL Error Library cannot be found 
FAILED - io_usb_dlopen
unable to load dll devu-ehci.so
```

At first I thought that it was a path issue, so I found the path to the file and appended it to the `$PATH` env var, but it didn't work. I tried `ldconfig /lib/dll/devu-ehci.so` but the command ldconfig doesn't exist. At this point I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. When I connect to the card with Tera Term, one of the first message is that the file system is in read only, could that be a problem ?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue with `io-usb -d ehci`. I updated the env var `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add the path to the .so file that couldn't be loaded:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/my/path"
```

then I had to follow the QNX guide and I can now see my USB storage with the `df -h` command.